# Clustering tags into categories with k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

Really new to this but I think I'm looking for K-means to do this.

I have a bunch of objects with tags (many). None of their other features matter. I know that similar objects have similar tags and they can be grouped into "categories". I'd like to know what these categories are (using k-means?). The tags look like...

[u'taste', u'healthy', u'recipe', u'vietnam', u'egg', u'soup', ...]

[u'kid', u'taste', u'healthy', u'school', u'recipe', u'family', ...]

[u'diet', u'tongue', u'health', u'beauty', u'hair',...]

[u'workout', u'athens', u'pizzino', u'henya', u'weight', u'loss',...]

Any tutorials or guides out there for lists of strings when using k-means? The order doesn't matter. I'm hoping the result can return back perhaps a clustered group of tags? Is that how it works? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K-means is based on variance minimization.

It tries to minimize the sum of squared deviations from the *mean*.

Because of this, it only works on continuous numerical variables, where you can compute the mean.

People have tried to embed other data as 0,1 vectors, but usually the results are pretty bad, and you cannot interpret results well anymore.

The "mean" is not a very suitable model for your task. Maybe rather look at frequent itemsets (or in your case: frequent tag sets)